# Multiple condition clause in C/ C++

Tags: c++

My aim is to get two numbers and perform an corresponding to the values they hold:

For ex.. Let the vars be **x** and **y**.

I need to compute the value of another var **z**, as follows:

**z** = **x** + **y** // if **x** = **y** = 1

**z** = **x** - **y** // if **x** = 0 and **y** = 1

Since i need to use it several times, it would not be efficient to use if else within a loop.

What i basically require is like a macro.... preferably using #define., like if it were to be used once:

**#define x + y 1** replaces x+y with 1, but does not depend on the values of **x** and/or **y**

Is there any way I could replace  x+y with 1, x-y with 0 and so on...

Comment: Why if-else if not efficient? It produces some c++-code but now much assembler-code. As Seth said in his answer: you cannot know the values of x and y at compiletime. **edit:** if you know that only these two cases can happen and no other cases then you could write: `z = x -y + 2*x` but if-else would better perform I think

Comment: based on d values at run time, i need to calculate... #define x+y 1 would suffice generally, but how do i make it obey to certain conditions as per run time vals

Comment: @thomas Using a single expression will perform more consistantly since it will always run the same instructions.  The if-else performance will depend on branch prediction and misses cost a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the vars are integers/any other primitive type you can't improve the performance, since the compile will usually translate it one assembly code line. such as `sub eax, ebx`

Anyhow, as mentioned before, you can't do it on compile time since x,y values are not known at compile time.

you can hint the compiler to save x and y on a register using the `register` keyword, which will save the variables on the CPU registers in order to preform faster calculations.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot know the values of `x` and `y` until runtime, so there is nothing you can do but use an `if` like you were going to and think of the math that will require the fewest operations (taking into account that 1 = subtraction = addition < multiplication < division usually).

If I misunderstood and you simply want to replace `x + y` with `1` and `x - y` with `0`, you can just replace them by hand or via find and replace.